# HTML table for chess coordinates

Tags: html-table

Hi I have to create a HTML table as a chess board that will show where king and queen are by showing a K and a Q in the cells they are in.

The original script I was doing was this;

```
if (kingX==queenX || kingY==queenY){
    alert('In Check!');
}
    else if (Math.abs(kingX - queenX)==Math.abs(kingY - queenY)){
        alert('In Check!');
    }
        else{
            alert('Not in Check!');
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [Element.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

Answer (score 0):

You can create elments with `document.createElement()` and the use `appendChild()` to append those elements to other, existing elements als last child element:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var i, j;
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    document.body.appendChild(table)
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        table.appendChild(row);
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            var cell = document.createElement('td');
            cell.textContent = i * 5 + j;
            cell.style.border = 'thin solid black';
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```